# Opening more than 150 ports on Azure VM using Azure SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I need to open more than 150 public ports on a single VM using the Azure SDK. Right now I am only limited to 150 ports, and when I try open any more using the azure sdk, I get a service error. Is there a way around this or a way to open more than 150 ports using the SDK?

Comment: Did you read the Virtual Machines limits section on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits) page?

Answer (score 0):

That problem was addressed in 2014. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/3995978-allow-to-open-more-ports-that-the-150-ports-limit by introducing the instnace-level public IP address that provides your virtual machine a full port range opened by default.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/instance-level-public-ip-address/